# Why the triangle diagram commutes because of naturality

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, natural-transformations

I am new in category and I am reading Awodey's [Category Theory](http://englishonlineclub.com/pdf/Category%20Teory%20%5BEnglishOnlineClub.com%5D.pdf). In the proof of Proposition 8.10 (See the picture of the proof [here1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T08r.png), [here2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUpDZ.png)
and [here3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgLqC.png)), after identifying $$x\in P(C)$$and
$$x:yC\rightarrow P$$
the author claims the diagram below commutes. But I can not see why.

[$\hspace{3cm}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZVJs.png)

The author says it comes from naturality in $C$ of Yoneda lemma(see the picture below), but I can not see it.
I am sorry I do not know how to put all the pictures in one link, so there are three parts of them. The proposition is also on the page 196-198 of the [book](http://englishonlineclub.com/pdf/Category%20Teory%20%5BEnglishOnlineClub.com%5D.pdf).

Here $y$ is the Yoneda embedding $\mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}} $ satisfying
$$yC=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(-,C):\mathbf{C}^{op}\rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}$$
and taking $f:C\rightarrow D$ to the natural transformation
$$yf=\operatorname{Hom}(-,f):\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(-,C)\rightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(-,D)$$

Thanks for any possible help!

Ps. The commutative diagram of Yoneda lemma in this book is as below. Details can be found on the page 189 of the book

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author claims in your second picture (See [here2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUpDZ.png)), that the triangle commutes due to the naturality of $C$, so you take the diagram explaining what this means in point (3) and apply it to your situation. We therefore have the following commuting diagram and we know $P(h)(x)=x'$ from equation (8.5) in your first picture (See [here1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T08r.png)):

[image]

This implies $\operatorname{Hom}(yh,P)(x)=x'$ for the corresponding natural transformations $x\colon yC\Rightarrow P$ and $x'\colon yC'\Rightarrow P$ using the Yoneda lemma (the horizontal arrows). Since $\operatorname{Hom}(yh,P)\colon\operatorname{Hom}(yC,P)\rightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(yC',P)$ is given by postcomposition with $yh\colon yC'\rightarrow yC$, we get the desired result:
$$yh\circ x=x'.$$

Comment: awesome！thank you